# How to fix jagged icon appearance in webstart/JNLP?

Tags: java, image, java-web-start

I created (downloaded and resized) a 64x64 icon that looks nice and smooth inside of the Gimp.

[image: Ahhh... smooth.]

But, when Java displays my icon during webstart, it looks jagged.  I tried both PNG and JPG formats.  I tried a 32x32 image, which looks even worse.

[image: Behold: jagginess]

Can anything be done?

Answer (score 0):

Java webstart has this problem that lowers the resolution of your icon if the dimension of your icon is missing in the jnlp file. Make sure you specify the actual width and height of your image like this:

```
<icon href="icon.png" width="64" height="64"/>
```

Comment: I have the dimensions.

Comment: Did you do anything special in Gimp to make your icon that smooth? Did you prehaps increase the DPI from its default value? The circles in your image seem too smooth for a 64 X 64 icon!

Comment: I did not do anything special (consciously).  But, perhaps you're on to something there.

Comment: I can also confirm that if icon has transparency it doesn't look good in Java webstart. This problem seem to be in windows only. The icon looks fine in Mac.